# Azure VM with Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 Update 3 with Azure SDK 2.9.1 on Microsoft is missing asp.net core templates

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2015

I created a **Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 Update 3 with Azure SDK 2.9.1 on Microsoft**.

I then started to create a asp.net core web application and found that it is not listed in the available templates.

Can anyone help me to know is there something that I am missing here.

Thanks,
Santosh

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the .NET core libraries?

https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#windows

I believe that is what actually installs the templates.

Comment: I tried the above but it was not allowing me to install.

Comment: Are you getting an error message? Do you have all of the dependencies installed that are listed?

Comment: I used Visual Studio 2015 Community edition and installed DotNetCore.1.0.0-VS2015Tools.Preview2.msi and it worked for me now.